# How to pass a different objects to the same function

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm a little bit lost with dynamic data and I will like your help.  This is what I'm trying to do:

I have the following Classes:

```
public class SmsMessage : MessageCommonDefinition
{
    public string MessageServiceKey { get; set; }
    public string MessageAttachments { get; set; }
    public bool MessageBodyUseTemplate { get; set; }
    public string MessageBodyTemplate { get; set; }
    public string MessageBodyTemplateValues { get; set; }
    public bool ValidateWithCarrier { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeCarrierInfo { get; set; }
}

public class EmailMessage : MessageCommonDefinition
{
    public string MessageDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string MessageCc { get; set; }
    public string MessageBcc { get; set; }
    public string MessageSubject { get; set; }
    public bool MessageIsBodyHtml { get; set; }
    public bool MessageBodyUseTemplate { get; set; }
    public string MessageBodyTemplate { get; set; }
    public string MessageBodyTemplateValues { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfidential { get; set; }
    public string MessageAttachments { get; set; }
    public MailPriority MessagePriority { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MessageCommonDefinition
{
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string MessageCode { get; set; }
    public string MessageChannelCode { get; set; }
    public string MessageTo { get; set; }
    public string MessageFrom { get; set; }
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    public string ChannelName { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a method to fill a template that receives, among other parameters, the type of message to fill the template (EmailMessage, SmSMessage, etc.)

This is the method:

```
if (triggerGroup.ToUpper().ToUpper() == AppSettingsKeys.External.ToString().ToUpper())
{
    List<PassengerTemplateEntity> passengerTemplateEntity = ACARSRepository.GetPassengerTemplateValues(emailMessage.MessageId);

    var passengerTemplateValues = DynamicClassBuilder.BuildObject();

    foreach (PassengerTemplateEntity passengerTemplate in passengerTemplateEntity)
    {
         passengerTemplateValues.AddProperty(passengerTemplate.FieldName, passengerTemplate.FieldData);
    }

    message.Body = Smart.Format(File.ReadAllText(attFilePath), passengerTemplateValues);

    message.Subject = emailMessage.IsConfidential ? SettingsManager.GetAppSettingValue(AppSettingsKeys.ConfidentialKey, "-secmsg-")
                        + " " + Smart.Format(emailMessage.MessageSubject.Trim(), passengerTemplateValues) : Smart.Format(emailMessage.MessageSubject.Trim(), passengerTemplateValues);
}
else if (triggerGroup.ToUpper() == AppSettingsKeys.Internal.ToString().ToUpper())
{
    alertTemplateValues = CoreRepository.GetExceptionMessage(emailMessage.MessageCode);

    if (alertTemplateValues != null)
    {
        message.Body = Smart.Format(File.ReadAllText(attFilePath), alertTemplateValues);
        message.Subject = Smart.Format(emailMessage.MessageSubject.Trim(), alertTemplateValues);
    }
    else
    {
        alertTemplateValues = CoreRepository.GetExceptionMessage("E127");
        throw new ArgumentException(Smart.Format("BlackBox.{0}: [Exception Code: {1}] {2}", alertTemplateValues.ShortName, alertTemplateValues.ExceptionCode, alertTemplateValues.ExceptionMessage), "ExceptionMessageCode: " + emailMessage.MessageCode, new ArgumentException());
    }
}
else
{
    alertTemplateValues = CoreRepository.GetExceptionMessage("E123");
    throw new ArgumentException(Smart.Format("BlackBox.{0}: [Exception Code: {1}] {2}", alertTemplateValues.ShortName, alertTemplateValues.ExceptionCode, alertTemplateValues.ExceptionMessage), "TriggerGroup: " + triggerGroup, new ArgumentException());
}
```

As you can see the method uses the emailMessage to retrieve values.  What I want to achieve is to use this as a shared function.  I want to send a generic parameter regardless it is an emailMessage or a SmsMessage and use the function by sending a generic object and fill the correct class with the correct value.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would flip this on its head. I would add `public abstract void SendMessage();` to `MessageCommonDefinition` and then put the code for sending each type of message in the message type classes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply. I already did that but I finished repetimg the same code for each message class.  If I can send the object dinamically I can use the same method for all my clases. Is that possible?

Comment: @Ray can you update the `MessageCommonDefinition` with what you did. If you've implemented  `SendMessage()` in both `EmailMessage` and `SmsMessage`, then any instance of either is simply `message.Send();`

Comment: I already got rid of the code but basically, and probably is because I dont understand the concept, I have more classes for different communication channels (email and sms were used as an example to simplify things).  Each time I want to send a message I need to validate if I need to fill a tamplate.  so the complete If code block will be call for each different instance.  If I use the abstract method how can I know what type of message is the one needed to be sent and to change the template.  This if is the emailmessage one but I dId the same for each one. How can I make it just once?